# What is image captioning and how is it used in Visual Question Answer?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to get me head around this but having difficulty.

As far as I understand:

> [Image Captioning](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-captioning-in-deep-learning-9cd23fb4d8d2) is the process of generating textual description of an image. It uses both Natural Language Processing and Computer Vision to generate the captions.

---

And from [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6632) paper:

> It directly models the probability distribution of generating a word given previous words and an image.

---

So if I understand correctly, using some model which takes image and previous text as input, it generates probabilities for the next word.

Taking an example from "Deep Visual-Semantic Alignments for Generating Image Descriptions" [paper](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/cvpr2015.pdf)

[image]

---

But how is that used in VQA (Visual Question Answering is a research area about building a computer system to answer questions presented in an image and a natural language. )?

Is the answer to a question taken from the caption generated from the image?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you fuse image features (CNN) and question features (RNN), pass these to another network with softmax output that corresponds to a one-word answer. See here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.00468v6.pdf

I can imagine trying a decoder network to produce sentences for answers, but those will be harder to evaluate.